# How to get only disintct values using Solr Search

Tags: php, solr

i'm new to solr search.I want to get disinct values of fields using solr.
I'm using `&rows=0&facet=on&facet.field=fieldname&wt=json`

Output:

```
facet_fields":{"packagename":["bangalore",2,"hyerabadd",2,"australia",3]
```

This is my code for decode above output:

```
<?php
header("Content-type:text/json");

$data=file_get_contents("http://localhost:8984/solr/collection1/select?q=*:*&rows=0&facet=on&facet.field=fieldname&wt=json");

$res=json_decode($data);

foreach($res->facet_counts->facet_fields as $doc){
    foreach($doc as $value){
      echo $value; 
    }
}
?>
```

Output after decode:

```
bangalore
2
hyderabad
2
australia
3
```

but,here i dont't want to display those numbers(min count).

Comment: i dont think its the problem with solr. You can skip the count while iterating through the array. Cant you?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti it won't work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolJSON#JSON_specific_parameters)

You can specify how the result should be returned in the JSON. Default is how it is shown above in your question. With json.nl=arrarr added to your query it will look like this

```
facet_fields":{ "packagename":[["bangalore",2],["hyerabadd",2],["australia",3]]
```

and it should be easier to distinguish between name and count